# MSYS2 CMake path prefix is in Windows format (C:/) but needs MSYS2/*nix style (/c/) to link

Tags: c++, cmake, msys2

The CMake installed from pacman within MSYS2 seems to prefix library and header/include paths with C:/, but the actual path format needed is a prefix of /c/. I've used a regex replace as a kludge but it's not a very elegant solution and I'm worried this will break things like MingW.

Just for reference the library path being obtianed by CMake is:

```
 C:/msys64/mingw64/include/gtk-3.0;C:/msys64/mingw64/include/cairo;C:/msys64/mingw64/include;C:/msys64/mingw64/include/pango-1.0;C:/msys64/mingw64/include/fribidi;C:/msys64/mingw64/include;C:/msys64/mingw64/include/atk-1.0;C:/msys64/mingw64/include/cairo;C:/msys64/mingw64/include/pixman-1;C:/msys64/mingw64/include;C:/msys64/mingw64/include/freetype2;C:/msys64/mingw64/include;C:/msys64/mingw64/include/harfbuzz;C:/msys64/mingw64/include/libpng16;C:/msys64/mingw64/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0;C:/msys64/mingw64/include/libpng16;C:/msys64/mingw64/include;C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/libffi-3.2.1/include;C:/msys64/mingw64/include/glib-2.0;C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/glib-2.0/include;C:/msys64/mingw64/include
```

and it needs to be:

```
 /c//msys64/mingw64/include/gtk-3.0;/c//msys64/mingw64/include/cairo;/c//msys64/mingw64/include;/c//msys64/mingw64/include/pango-1.0;/c//msys64/mingw64/include/fribidi;/c//msys64/mingw64/include;/c//msys64/mingw64/include/atk-1.0;/c//msys64/mingw64/include/cairo;/c//msys64/mingw64/include/pixman-1;/c//msys64/mingw64/include;/c//msys64/mingw64/include/freetype2;/c//msys64/mingw64/include;/c//msys64/mingw64/include/harfbuzz;/c//msys64/mingw64/include/libpng16;/c//msys64/mingw64/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0;/c//msys64/mingw64/include/libpng16;/c//msys64/mingw64/include;/c//msys64/mingw64/lib/libffi-3.2.1/include;/c//msys64/mingw64/include/glib-2.0;/c//msys64/mingw64/lib/glib-2.0/include;/c//msys64/mingw64/include
```

I've been digging for a solution and saw that CMake for Windows (not the CMake installed from within MSYS2) has a MSYS specific makefile generator, but there must be some simple solution to use the CMake available within MSYS2. I can't imagine I'm the only one who's encountered this issue. Does anyone know of a clean solution?

UPDATE:
Here is the CMakeLists.txt without the regex replace hack. This fails with the error

```
C:/msys64/home/username/sample/src/main.cpp:1:10 fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
 #include <gtk/gtk.h>

compilation terminated.
```

during make.

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)

    project(sample CXX)

    # Find GTK+ headers/libs with PkgConfig
    find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
    pkg_check_modules(GTK3 REQUIRED gtk+-3.0)

    include_directories(${GTK3_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    link_directories(${GTK3_LIBRARY_DIRS})

    add_definitions(${GTK3_CFLAGS_OTHER})

    set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib/natives)
    set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib/natives)
    set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)

    add_executable(sample src/main.cpp)

    target_link_libraries(sample ${GTK3_LIBRARIES})
```

For main.cpp just use the default GTK+ hello world

```cpp
    #include <gtk/gtk.h>

    int
    main (int   argc,
    char *argv[])
    {
      GtkWidget *window;

      gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

      window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

      g_signal_connect (window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit), NULL);

      gtk_widget_show (window);

      gtk_main ();

      return 0;
    }
```

To make compilation work, I'm using the following CMake kludge:

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)

    project(sample CXX)

    # Find GTK+ headers/libs with PkgConfig
    find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
    pkg_check_modules(GTK3 REQUIRED gtk+-3.0)

    # Generated paths starting with "C:" need to be converted to /c/ to work with MSYS2
    # TODO remove this or do it some way better at some point in the future
    if(MSYS OR MINGW)
        string(REGEX REPLACE "C:" "/c/" GTK3_INCLUDE_DIRS "${GTK3_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
    endif(MSYS OR MINGW)

    include_directories(${GTK3_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    link_directories(${GTK3_LIBRARY_DIRS})

    add_definitions(${GTK3_CFLAGS_OTHER})

    set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib/natives)
    set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib/natives)
    set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)

    add_executable(sample src/main.cpp)

    target_link_libraries(sample ${GTK3_LIBRARIES})
```

Note the REGEX REPLACE.

Another thing to note is I'm only using tools, such as cmake, and libraries/headers/etc. installed from pacman within MSYS2 and I'd prefer to keep it that way because I'll be rolling something out based on this as a Ruby native extension and the Windows SDK for that is MSYS2 based. At the same time, I'm fairly sure my kludge will break MingW based builds (if I even need to worry about that?) and it's not very flexible.

Comment: I could show you what I figured out for building and installing libraries with CMake in MSYS2, but I'm not sure it will solve your problem because you didn't say what the problem actually is.  What is the exact problem you are having?  Are libraries getting installed to the wrong location?  What do you mean by "the library path obtianed by CMake"?  How is it obtained and what problems does it cause?

Comment: The library paths are prefixed with C:, which I think is how MingW wants them (but I'm not sure), but MSYS2 uses /c as the root prefix. I'm not completely sure where the paths are coming from but I have a feeling it's PkgConfig.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: There's not much I can do to help if you won't say what you are doing and what error message you are getting.

Comment: I've updated the question to include a detailed sample; but I think you've misread my question a bit. The problem is literally that the paths being accumulated by CMake and inserted into the makefile are all prefixed with "C:/", which is incompatible with MSYS2 as the C drive root prefix in MSYS2 is "/c/" and MSYS2 does not recognize C:/ as a valid path prefix. I could probably alias it somehow, but I feel like that could be a worse hack than just regex replacing the path strings like I am now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has to do with how MingW packages are/were ported to MSYS2. The paths are in "Windows" format for backwards compatibility and to preserve compatibility with systems like Visual Studio. The only answer is to do regex replace like I've pointed out above or to just recompile the libraries in MSYS2 like I've now chosen to do.

As a general guideline, packages available in MSYS2 without mingw prefixes in the package names don't have this "backward compatibility" issue and, as far as I know, don't require such a workaround.